# For loop for the first row, the button cant work

Tags: php, database, button

This is the table i created , so when i press the Edit button it should bring me to another page to edit. For the first edit button on the first row it does not work however for the rest of the  edit button on the second row onward it works. Please help. Thank you !

```
   <table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th width='120'>Production ID</th>
                <th width='120'>Description</th>
                <th width='120'>BOM</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
                $fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($select);
                echo "<tr>
 <td>" . $fetch[0] . "</td>
 <td>" . $fetch[1] . "</td>
 <td>" . $fetch[2] . "</td>
 <td><form action='AddProductMainEdit.php?prodid' method='GET'><input type='hidden'       value='".$fetch[0]."' name='prodid'><input type='submit' id='edit' value='Edit'></form></td>
 </tr>";
            }
            ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Check out the generated HTML with something like CTRL-U in the browser. That should hopefully turn up any differences between the first and subsequent rows. And, what if I'm an athiest, or worse, a devil worshipper. "Thanks in advance" may be better than "God bless you" :-)

Comment: why the `for` is before the fetch?

Comment: yup i check all of the rows is the same

Comment: the for loop is to see how many records in my database then i fetch my individual column ? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: maybe is just a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <table border='1'>
     <tr>
         <th width='120'>Production ID</th>
         <th width='120'>Description</th>
         <th width='120'>BOM</th>
         </tr>
 <?php
    while ($fetch=mysqli_fetch_row($select)) {
      echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $fetch[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $fetch[1] . "</td>
            <td>" . $fetch[2] . "</td>
            <td><form action='AddProductMainEdit.php' method='GET'><input type='hidden'  value='".$fetch[0]."' name='prodid'><input type='submit' id='edit' value='Edit'></form></td>
            </tr>";
    }
?>
 </table>
```

You don't need to add the variable `prodid` to the url, the get method add all the variables to the url.

Comment: i have try but is still the same. only the second row onward the button works

Comment: What value are you getting on the first row in `$fetch[0]`?

Comment: it still cant work. but anyway thanks for your effort =)

Comment: Did you try closing the `input` elements: `<input type='hidden'  value='".$fetch[0]."' name='prodid' />`

Comment: <td><form action='AddProductMainEdit.php?' method='GET'><input type='hidden'       value='".$fetch[0]."' name='prodid'></input><input type='submit' id='edit' value='Edit'></input></form></td>

Comment: maybe is bad luck day haha

Comment: Are you using the while instead the for?

Comment: <table border='1'>
     <tr>
         <th width='120'>Production ID</th>
         <th width='120'>Description</th>
         <th width='120'>BOM</th>
         </tr>
 <?php
    while ($fetch=mysqli_fetch_row($select)) {
      echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $fetch[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $fetch[1] . "</td>
            <td>" . $fetch[2] . "</td>
            <td><form action='AddProductMainEdit.php?' method='GET'><input type='hidden'       value='".$fetch[0]."' name='prodid'></input><input type='submit' id='edit' value='Edit'></input></form></td>
            </tr>";
    }
?>
 </table>

Comment: i am using the while loop you give me

Comment: You have a `?`in your URL and </input> don't exist... don't make any difference but is the correct way.